# Arc Progress Bar with constant image inside

Tags: android, android-animation, android-progressbar

How do I create a Arc Progress bar animation with constant image inside of it like this [image]

Comment: What library are you using to implement this progress bar?

Comment: @AhmedAlnabhan https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@android:id/background">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="12.0"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bg" />
    </shape>

</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="12.0">
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#cc44b9ff"
            android:startColor="#cc9730ff"
            android:type="linear" />

    </shape>

</item>
```

Layer List is the a kind drawable first item represents the background and second item represents how the progress bar should be.

Note: ID of second item should be `android:id="@android:id/progress"`, you can remove gradient if you want to be plain color.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using that library then use

```
 <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="Required Text"/>
```